# Bash autocompletion for an environment variable holding a directory name

Tags: bash, autocomplete

I'm using, among other things, bash 4.2.37 on Linux Mint 14.

When I autocomplete the name of an environment variable by typing <kbd>Tab</kbd>, it expands to the name of the variable followed by a space.

If the value of the variable happens to be a directory name, I want it to expand to the name of the variable followed by `/`.

For example, if I type:

```
$ ls $HOM<tab>
```

it expands to:

```
$ ls $HOME _
```

where `_` marks the location of the cursor.  The problem is that I then usually want to continue typing the name of some file or directory under my home directory, which means I have to type <kbd>backspace</kbd> and then `/`.

So I *want* the above to expand to:

```
$ ls $HOME/_
```

The same thing happens when I've typed the entire variable name; after `ls $HOME`, <kbd>tab</kbd> adds a space, and I want it to add a `/`.

(And of course I don't want it to add a `/` if the variable's value is not a directory name.)

Is there some way I can tell bash to behave the way I want, either via bash commands or by updating my `$HOME/.inputrc`?

Note: I'm specifically looking for a way to make <kbd>tab</kbd> behave the way I want. Ways to achieve the same behavior with different keystrokes would be interesting, but would not answer my question.

(I've disabled `/etc/profile.d/bash_completion.sh` on my system because it interacts poorly with `set -o nounset`. A quick experiment indicates that this is probably not relevant to my question.)

Incidentally, tcsh does this: given an environment variable `$FOOBAR`, typing `$FOOBA<tab>` expands to `$FOOBAR/` if it refers to a directory, `$FOOBAR` (with a space) if it doesn't. No, that's not enough to persuade me to go back to tcsh. zsh does this as well.

Comment: +1 In case you feel adventurous, [here's the code](https://savannah.gnu.org/git/?group=bash).

Comment: @l0b0: (a) I already have it. (b) I'm not feeling quite *that* adventurous. (c) It's suppose to be *programmable* completion.

Answer (score 7):

```
shopt -s direxpand
```

will help. There will be no space, so you can continue typing, but it will replace the environment variable with its content.

See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6418493/bash-variable-expansion-on-tab-complete

Answer (score 6):

This feature is implemented in bash 4.3, released 2014-02-26.

Quoting the `NEWS` file (included at the top level of [`bash-4.3.tar.gz`](ftp://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/bash/bash-4.3.tar.gz), see also the [GPG signature](ftp://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/bash/bash-4.3.tar.gz.sig)):

> The word completion code checks whether or not a filename containing a
>   shell variable expands to a directory name and appends `/` to the word
>   as appropriate.  The same code expands shell variables in command
>   names when performing command completion.

A quick experiment with a copy built from source shows that if I type

```
$ ls $HOM<tab>
```

it now expands to

```
$ ls $HOME/
```

(Incidentally, zsh also does this.)

Comment: Had to install bash manually for this. 4.3 isn't in the fedora 20 repos.

Comment: !! Looks like `zsh` actually does even better: it keeps the environment variable as is but expands after it. I seriously might switch.